# NextGen image gallery - how to get next image url

Tags: php, wordpress, image-gallery, nextgen-gallery

Is there any way to get url for next image when using **NextGEN Basic ImageBrowser** gallery type?

I'm also using ajax pagination.

There are next and previous buttons but inside code

```
<?php echo $next_image_link; ?>
```

returns

```
/nggallery/image/xgen-5-1/
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code for show your pictures:

```
<?php
echo "<img src='".$next_image_link."' />
?>
```

Comment: That's what I get:
<img src="/test/nggallery/image/filename-1/">

Comment: show a part of your code ... ajax and your directories @Nitrak

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you are using Image browser type where the 'Back' and 'Next' buttons are available (Reference link - http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/nextgen-gallery-demos/ : Imagebrowser).

If you hover over the 'Next' button, you will be able to see URL of the next image. Now, you can make use of that. If you want to do something with it on your browser, you can access it via a JavaScript code and do whatever you want. 
However, if you want to get the URL of the next image via PHP code, then you can print the gallery object via code by doing `print_r()` or `var_dump()`, see which are the available images in the entire gallery and pull the image URLs by your PHP code.